# IMCUS $2003$ problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

> Prove that for all $\alpha>1$ there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers with $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}>3a_n/2$ for all $n\ge 1$ such that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{(3/2)^{n-1}}=\alpha$
>   $\tag{IMCUS 2003}$
>
> ---

Denoting $b_n=\frac{a_n}{(3/2)^{n-1}},$ the hypothesis that $a_{n+1}>3a_n/2$ implies that $b_{n+1}>b_n.$  So I know that the sequence is increasing. So I want $\alpha$ to be the supremum of $\{b_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ How do I go about choosing $a_{n+1}?$ Is the question asking for an expression for $a_{n+1}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the question asking for an expression for $a_{n+1}?$

The question appears to be asking for a proof of existence, only, in which case you only need to take the last step and state that *any* strictly increasing sequence $1 = b_1 \lt b_2 \lt \cdots \,$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \alpha$
gives a sequence $a_n = (\frac{3}{2})^{n-1} b_n$ which satisfies the requirements.

For an explicit form of such a sequence, you could use for example:

$$b_n=\alpha - \frac{\alpha-1}{n} \quad \implies \quad a_n = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1} \left(\alpha - \frac{\alpha-1}{n}\right)$$